# Drop down value not captured with selenium page factory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

Below is my `@findby` annotation with method, help to to get the value:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*[@id='Voucher']") 
public WebElement DropDownVoucherName;

public void voucher_ddp(String vddp) { 
    try { 
        Select vdp = new Select(DropDownVoucherName); vdp.selectByValue(vddp); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Error found: "+e.getMessage()); 
    } 
}
```

Error getting:

> NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with value : xyz

Comment: Please share the page html dom details.

Comment: @SudhaVelan please have a look  <select class="form-control" id="Voucher" name="Voucher"><option value="">- Select Voucher -</option>
<option value="44">Bank Receipt</option>
<option value="45">Cash Receipt</option>
<option value="135">OR BRV</option>
<option value="145">OR CRV</option>
</select>

Comment: @AmitAggarwal as per the exception you are trying to click on "xyz" value from the dropdown but according to your html structure, there is no "xyz" value. What is the value that you want to select from the dropdown

Comment: @AmitAggarwal Are you sure you select by Value and not by visible text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you've initialised page factory in constructor with

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, ClassName.class);
```